# SSIS: Column 'column_name' cannot be found at the datasource

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am working on a SSIS project. I am trying to run a query into a file. In my package, I have an OLE DB Source that runs this query.

```
USE [DB]

SET FMTONLY OFF;

DECLARE @table_data TABLE 
                    (
                        column_01 VARCHAR(255),
                        column_02 VARCHAR(10),
                        column_04 VARCHAR(255)
                    )

SELECT 
    'column_01',
    'column_02',
    'column_03'
UNION ALL 
        column_01,
        column_02,
        column_03
FROM 
    @table_data
```

When I try to run the script, I get this error:

> SSIS: Column 'column_01' cannot be found at the datasource

I tried setting the `ValidateExternalMetaData` on and I get an error (`failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA"`).

The OLE DB Source is dumping the data into a dynamic text file.

I don't know how to fix this or understand why SSIS is not allowing me to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not generate an error; see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f64e2bd9ace80beac2a6e80383cb9b47).

I suspect, though, that you are expecting your results to have columns with *names*.  But they are just anonymous strings.  What you want is rather unclear.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT 'column_01' as column_01, 'column_02' as column_02,
       'column_03' as column_03
FROM @table_data;
```

Or perhaps you want the values from the table rather than constant string values:

```
SELECT column_01, column_02,column_03
FROM @table_data;
```

Comment: i updated my sql code. I made a mistake... i tried adding an alias to all my columns and it still cannot be found at the datasource

Comment: By any miracle have you solved this issue?  
It is happening to me now, but ONLY when I run the package.
When I run the container OR the task, it works just fine.

If I pause on the data flow task, go into the data flows and select the code that failed  data source runs, it will run perfectly.  This just makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like bellow. It is working without any error.

```
USE [DB]

SET FMTONLY OFF;

DECLARE @table_data TABLE 
                    (
                        column_01 VARCHAR(255),
                        column_02 VARCHAR(10),
                        column_04 VARCHAR(255)
                    )

INSERT INTO @table_data
SELECT 'column_01','column_02','column_03'

SELECT * FROM @table_data
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

after union you must use `select` 
like this:

```
USE [DB]

SET FMTONLY OFF;

DECLARE @table_data TABLE 
                    (
                        column_01 VARCHAR(255),
                        column_02 VARCHAR(10),
                        column_04 VARCHAR(255)
                    )

SELECT 
    'column_01',
    'column_02',
    'column_03'

UNION ALL 

select
        column_01,
        column_02,
        column_03
FROM 
    @table_data
```